# Buggy "Announcer" badge?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, badges

I received an announcer badge for a question. Supposedly, the badge is for sharing a question such that it attracts visitors from 25 unique IP addresses. Problem is, I've never shared a question, and have never laid eyes on that question to my best recollection.

What is that about?

Comment: Which question? I know we could go an look on your profile, but it's easier if you include the link here.

Comment: It is this one: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/125926/what-is-problem-domain

Comment: Free badge! Yay!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Heh... You got *lucky*.

See, [Sam *The Brand* Brand](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/users/39006/samthebrand) has been doing this syndication deal with the respected tech-news site ArsTechnica. Today, they republished some of the top answers from [Is there an excuse for short variable names?](http://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2013/02/is-there-an-excuse-for-short-variable-names/)...

[...Including yours...](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/176582/is-there-an-excuse-for-short-variable-names/176611#176611)

...Wherein you link to that "problem domain" question using the referral format:

> The code simply assumes the [problem domain](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/125926/50950) familiarity.

Now, *normally* using the referral shortlink in an answer doesn't do much for you; we don't count links from *within* Stack Exchange when figuring up these badges. But of course, if someone copies the text of your answer (hopefully [in a CC-Wiki-compliant fashion](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/)) to another domain and it generates a bunch of inbound links, well...

> Free badge! Yay! – [Yannis Rizos](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5505/buggy-announcer-badge#comment13887_5505)

Comment: Except that there's no link in the original post. It's something that got added to the Ars version of the post.

Comment: I thought something is fishy because I did recall writing something about problem domains. Just not a link to that question.

Comment: Heh... Well, I'm gonna blame the editor then. I'll pass this on to Sam.

Comment: I still don't get it because when I look at the ArsTechnica clone, the URL which it provides doesn't contain anything which connects it to me. No hidden URL parameter like `&user=kaz` or whatever. It seems that SE would have to pull the page out of the referal info from the browser and parse that page, then realize, aha, that link that the user used was in a section written by Kaz, which maps back to a SE user.

Comment: @Kaz URL at arstechnica is `http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/125926/50950`, where `50950` is that "hidden parameter", your userId at programmers, check how it refers to your profile there: `http://programmers.stackexchange.com/users/50950`